# vnoremap to sort highlighted lines by length not working as expected

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings, macvim

I found a command that would sort highlighted lines by their length and wanted to make a mapping for it so that I could avoid typing it every time.

```
vnoremap ,s :<C-U>'<,'> ! awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -n | cut -d\\  -f2-" }'<CR>
```

However, when I try to use the remapping, only the following is seen:

```
:'<,'> ! awk '{ print length(), $0
```

It abruptly stops at `$0` and does not complete the rest of the command.

I don't know what I am doing wrong; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the \" is seen as starting a comment. Try to escape the double quotation

Comment: You'll also need to write `<bar>` or `\|` instead of `|`

Comment: replacing | with <bar> worked. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping command, like most of the Vim commands, can be part of a list of commands `|` separated.

When executed the following line:

```
nnoremap mm :echo "foo" | echo "bar"
```

is equivalent to the script:

```
nnoremap mm :echo "foo"
echo "bar"
```

If you like the `|` to be part of the mapping it has to be escaped as `\|` or as `<bar>`.

Because mappings simulate keys, the mapping itself use the `<` escaping:

- `<lt>` stands for `<`
- `<char-65>` stands for `A`
- `<C-s>` stands for <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>
- `<bar>` stands for `|`
- ...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the solution accordingly :-)

Comment: I saw you were doing but I didn't dare, still too green :-) I'll do in the future.